# How can I add an interaction term between Income and Employment to this multiple linear regression model in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I have successfully made a regression model with some terms in Python. How would I add an interaction term between **Income** and **Employment** to this model?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn import linear_model
import statsmodels.api as sm

X = dat[['Median Houseold Income', "Bachelor's Degree or Higher", 'Employment']]
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
lm = reg.fit(X, dat.Turnout)
lm

print('Intercept: \n', reg.intercept_)
print('Coefficients: \n', reg.coef_)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `interaction term`?

Comment: Like a term to represent Employment x Income @pissall

Comment: create new column `dat["Interaction_Term"] = dat["Employment"] * dat["Median Houseold Income"]`